# When is a stable $\infty$-category the stabilization of an $\infty$-topos?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, stable-homotopy, infinity-topos-theory

Let $\mathcal X$ be a presentable $\infty$-category. Then the [stabilization](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stabilization) $Stab(\mathcal X)$ of $\mathcal X$ is the universal presentable stable category on $\mathcal X$.

Conversely, if $\mathcal A$ is a presentable stable $\infty$-category, then we can ask which presentable $\infty$-categories $\mathcal X$ have $Stab(\mathcal X) \simeq \mathcal A$. There's always at least one such $\mathcal X$, namely $\mathcal A$ itself. In particular, I would like to know an answer to the following:

**Question 1:** Let $\mathcal A$ be a presentable stable $\infty$-category. Under what conditions does there exist an $\infty$-topos $\mathcal X$ such that $Stab(\mathcal X) \simeq \mathcal A$?

For a closely related question, let $StPr^L$ denote the $\infty$-category of presentable stable $\infty$-categories and left adjoint functors. Let $Logoi$ denote the $\infty$-category of $\infty$-topoi, with geometric morphisms pointing in the direction of their *inverse* images.

**Question 2:** Does the functor $Stab : Logoi \to StPr^L$ have a left or right adjoint?

If the answer to Question 2 is affirmative, then one might approach Question 1 by asking for criteria ensuring that the unit / counit of the adjunction is an equivalence. Alternatively, one might wonder

<strike>**Question 3:** Note that the functor $Stab : Pr^L \to StPr^L$ has both a left adjoint $L$ and a right adjoint $R$. For which presentable stable $\infty$-categories $\mathcal A$ is $L\mathcal A$ or $R \mathcal A$ an $\infty$-topos?</strike>

**Question 4:** For example, let $G$ be a compact (even finite, say) Lie group. Is the category $Spt_G$ of genuine $G$-spectra the stabilization of an $\infty$-topos?

Comment: I don't think $Stab$ has a left adjoint, does it ? For instance, it does not preserve the pullback $Spaces \times_{CMon} CGrp = 0$ (along the free functor and the inclusion) Also, its right adjoint $R$ is the forgetful functor, so $R\mathcal A$ is never a topos unless $\mathcal A$ is, which I think happens iff $\mathcal A = 0$.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Oh you're right -- it's rather that the right adjoint itself has a right adjoint. Hm... so Question 3 seems to be a dead end

Comment: I think there's always a symmetric monoidal "smash product" on $Stab(\mathcal X)$ arising from the cartesian product on $\mathcal X$. It may make sense to take such a symmetric monoidal structure as part of the input when trying to reconstruct a topos $\mathcal X$.

Comment: @TimCampion stabilizing the cartesian product doesn’t give a symmetric monoidal struture in general - this “multiplicative structure” from differentiating the cartesian product only exhibits Sp(X) as an operad. This is discussed in HA 6.2.4 and also in the thesis of Heuts.

Comment: @Bbb sure but stabilization is a symmetric monoidal functor from PrL to stprl so it does turn any presentable Cartesian closed category into a symmetric monoidal closed stable category

Comment: @TimCampion but that wouldn’t look anything like the smash product right? I might be confused but wouldn’t that give you Sp(X) with its cartesian monoidal structure?

Comment: @Bbb the cartesian monoidal structure on an additive category is not closed, but the monoidal structure I’m talking about is closed, so they are very different. The cartesian monoidal structure on the topos induces a very much non cartesian monoidal structure on the stabilization. Eg this is exactly how the smash product of spectra is induced by the cartesian product of spaces

Comment: Ah thanks @TimCampion indeed I was being silly. Although trying to reconstruct X from the stable operad structure coming from differentiation as I suggested above could be interesting as well.

Comment: A side note, but calling that category of infinity-toposes “logoi” seems peculiar — the established use of “logos” I’m familiar with is typically to distinguish *elementary* (infinity-)toposes and *logical* morphisms, by contrast with Grothendieck (infinity-)toposes and geometric morphisms; or else something closely analogous to this, distinguishing the logical category from the geometric.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine that seems reasonable. I’m just following the usage of Joyal et al. And I’m the oo-categorical setting, still nobody knows what a “logical morphism “ should be.

Comment: Is even the $1$-categorial version of that known (for $1$-topos and Grothendieck abelian categories)?

Answer (score 7):

For any topos $\mathcal{X}$, we have $Stab(\mathcal{X})=Sh_{Sp}(\mathcal{X})$, so our topos admits a symmetric monoidal adjunction with $\mathcal{A}$ (just as in the case $\mathcal{X}=\infty Gpd$). To be precise, the smash product of spectra will yield a tensor product on sheaves of spectra, so $\mathcal{A}$ must be symmetric monoidal. As you observed, the suspension map $\mathcal{X}\to\mathcal{A}$ must preserve the symmetric monoidal structure because it does so for the case of spaces (and $\mathcal{X}=Sh_{\infty Gpd}(\mathcal{X})$). So that's one obstruction.

We can also equip a stabilized topos with a natural t-structure (coming from its construction as sheaves of spectra; see Prp 1.3.2.7 in Lurie's SAG) which is right complete and compatible with filtered colimits. The heart of this t-structure is the category of abelian group objects in the underlying $1$-topos $\mathcal{X}^{♡}$. That's another obstruction: $\mathcal{A}$ must admit a right-complete t-structure, and the heart must be a Grothendieck category.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another sort of constraint. I'll write $Sp(\mathcal C)$ instead of $Stab(\mathcal C)$.

**Claim:** If $\mathcal A \simeq Sp(\mathcal X)$ for a nontrivial [1] $\infty$-topos $\mathcal X$, then for any nontrivial localization $Spectra_L$ of $Spectra$, the localization $\mathcal A_L$ is a nontrivial localization of $\mathcal A$.

---

For instance, this means that the derived category $D(X)$ of a ring or scheme is never the stabilization of an $\infty$-topos, since $D(X)$ is fixed by the nontrivial localization at $H\mathbb Z$.

---

Let $\mathcal X$ be a nontrivial $\infty$-topos, and let $x^* : Spaces {}^\to_\leftarrow \mathcal X : x_*$ be the unique geometric morphism to $Spaces$. Let us contemplate the accessible left exact functor $\xi = x_* x^* : Spaces \to Spaces$ (the "shape" of $\mathcal X$). Note that

1. $\xi$ preserves and reflects the initial object $\emptyset \in Spaces$;

"Preserves" is because if the initial object $x^\ast \emptyset = \emptyset_{\mathcal X}$ had a global section $1 \to \emptyset$, then $\mathcal X$ would be trivial. "Reflects" is because any nonempty space has the terminal space $1$ as a retract, and $\xi$ preserves $1$.

2. If $X \to Y \leftarrow Z$ are maps in $Spaces$ with empty pullback, then $\xi X \to \xi Y \leftarrow \xi Z$ likewise has empty pullback.

This follows from (1) since $\xi$ is left exact. Therefore

3. If $X \in Spaces$ is disconnected, then so is $\xi(X)$.

For we can take different connected components of $X$ in (2) above. It now follows that

4. The functor $Sp(\xi) : Spectra \to Spectra$ induced by $\xi$ is conservative.

This functor is induced by applying $\xi$ levelwise to each $\Omega$-spectrum. To verify the claim, note that if $0 \neq E \in Spectra$, then $E_n$ is disonnected for some $n$ (where we think of $E$ as an $\Omega$-spectrum $(E_n)_{n \in \mathbb Z}$). By (3), $Sp(\xi)(E)_n = \xi(E_n)$ is disconnected, and hence $Sp(\xi)(E) \neq 0$. As an exact, zero-reflecting functor between stable categories, this implies that $Sp(\xi)$ is conservative.

It now follows that

**Theorem:** Let $\mathcal X$ be a nontrivial $\infty$-topos, and let $x^\ast : Spaces \to \mathcal X$ be the inclusion of constant objects. Then the induced functor $Sp(x^\ast) : Spectra \to Sp(\mathcal X)$ is conservative.

This follows from (4) since postcomposing $Sp(x_\ast)$ results in the conservative functor $Sp(x_\ast x^\ast)$.

**Proof of Claim:**

Note that there is an adjunction $Sp(x^\ast) \dashv Sp(x_\ast)$. If $Sp(\mathcal X) = Spectra_L \otimes Sp(\mathcal X)$, then the left adjoint $Sp(x^\ast) : Spectra \to Sp(\mathcal X)$ factors through $Spectra_L$, contradicting the Theorem.

---

[1] An $\infty$-topos $\mathcal X$ is "nontrivial" if it is not equivalent to the the terminal $\infty$-category, i.e. if the map from the initial object to the terminal object of $\mathcal X$ is not an equivalence.