# Is the category of modules over a commutative ring the category of abelian objects in a topos?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, topos-theory

The categories of modules over commutative rings are especially notable Abelian categories. Wanting to extend this class a bit, I thought of this question:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$. Does there exist a Grothendieck topos $E$ such that $\mathrm{Ab}(E) \simeq R\text{-}\mathrm{Mod}$ (equivalence of categories)?

See the related question I was able to find: [Is every Grothendieck category with a generator a category of sheaves?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333955/is-every-grothendieck-category-with-a-generator-a-category-of-sheaves)

Comment: If $E$ is a topos which has a point $x$, then the topos $Set$ is a retract (in the category of topoi) of $E$. It follows that $Ab = Ab(Set)$ is a retract of $Ab(E)$. So for instance $Ab(E)$ can't be $Vect_k$ for $k$ a field. I suspect that the hypothesis of $E$ having a point can be lifted by arguments along the lines [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/434353/2362) (or maybe the result there can be used directly by passing to hearts of $t$-structures). In short, I'm pretty sure the answer is _no_ in general.

Comment: Here are some examples of commutative rings whose module categories are the abelian group objects in a topos.

 1. If $M$ is a commutative monoid, then the category of $\mathbb ZM$-modules is equivalent to the category of abelian group objects in the topos of $M$-sets.
 2. If $X$ is a compact totally disconnected space and $R$ is the ring of locally constant functions from $X$ to $\mathbb Z$, then the category of $R$-modules is equivalent to the category of sheaves of abelian groups on $X$, which is of course the abelian group objects in the topos of sheaves of sets on $X$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No — in particular, not if $R$ has any non-integer rationals.**

Briefly: From $\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}\newcommand{\Ab}{\mathrm{Ab}}\newcommand{\RMod}{{R\text{-}\mathrm{Mod}}}\RMod$, we can recover $R$ as the ring of endomorphisms of the identity functor, $\newcommand{\End}{\mathrm{End}}\newcommand{\id}{\mathrm{id}}R \cong \End(\id_\RMod)$.  But for a topos $\newcommand{\E}{\mathcal{E}}\E$, $\End(\id_{\Ab(\E)})$ retracts onto $\Gamma(\Z_\E)$ (global sections of the integers of $\E$); and this will never have any non-trivial rationals.

Unwinding this more elementarily: Suppose $n \in \Z$ is invertible in $R$, with $n \neq \pm 1$. Then multiplication by $\frac{1}{n}$ gives a natural endomorphism $\mu_{\frac{1}{n}}$ of the identity functor on $\RMod$, satisfying $n \cdot \mu_{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$ (where $1$ is the identity endomorphism of the identity functor).

But the $\mathbf{Ab}$-enrichment of any Abelian category is determined by the category structure ([using the biproducts](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/biproduct#BiproductsImplyEnrichment)). So an equivalence $\RMod \cong \Ab(\E)$ would transfer $\mu_{\frac{1}{n}}$ to an endomorphism $\mu'$ of $\id_{\Ab(\E)}$ with $n \cdot \mu' = 1$; then applying this at $\Z_\E$, and taking global sections, would give an inverse for $n$ in $\Gamma(\Z_\E)$.  But this can never exist unless $\E$ is the trivial topos, since as $n$ is non-unital you can prove constructively “$n$ is not invertible in $\Z$”, so this holds in the internal language of $\E$.  So then $\Ab(\E)$ is also trivial, and the equivalence $\RMod \cong \Ab(\E)$ implies $R \cong 1$.

So we’ve shown: **if an integer $n \neq \pm 1$ is invertible in $R$, and $\RMod \cong \Ab(\E)$, then $R$ is the zero ring.**

Comment: I think it is not true that the endomorphism of the identity gives the global section of the integer: consider the case of the topos of M-set for M a commutative monoid

Comment: Great! Could you expand on why $n$ can't be invertible in $Ab(\mathcal E)$ unless $\mathcal E$ is trivial?

Comment: @TimCampion : you can proove constructively that integers are not invertible.

Comment: @SimonHenry: Oops, good catch — yes, $\Gamma(\mathbb{Z})(\mathcal{E})$ isn’t generally isomorphic to $\mathrm{End}(\mathrm{id}_{\mathrm{Ab}(\mathcal{E})})$ as I’d claimed.  But it’s still a retract, which is enough for the argument to go through.

Comment: How do you see that $\Gamma(\mathbb{Z}_\mathcal{E})$ is a retract of $\mathrm{End}(\mathrm{id}_{\mathrm{Ab}(\mathcal{E})})$?
It is not needed for the argument: for that it is enough that there is a ring morphism $\mathrm{End}(\mathrm{id}_{\mathrm{Ab}(\mathcal{E})}) \to \Gamma(\mathbb{Z}_\mathcal{E})$. But I would be interested regardless.

Comment: @JensHemelaer: For the map $\newcommand{\End}{\mathrm{End}}\newcommand{\id}{\mathrm{id}}\newcommand{\Ab}{\mathrm{Ab}}\newcommand{\E}{\mathcal{E}}\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}\End(\id_{\Ab(\E)}) \to \Gamma(\Z_\E)$: given an endomorphism of $\id_{\Ab(\E)}$, apply it at $\Z_\E$ and take global sections to get an ab-gp endomorphism of $\Gamma(\Z_\E)$, then apply it to $1$.  Conversely, any $A$ in $\Ab(\E)$ has a natural $\Z_\E$-action $\Z_\E \times A \to A$; so a global section $s : 1 \to \Z_\E$ gives a natural map $s_A : A \to A$.  Checking these give a retraction is a follow-your-nose computation.

Comment: Nice argument, thanks!